# CopyFile API function not working after using GetOpenFileName to get the file path

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder, c++builder-6

I am using [`GetOpenFileName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927.aspx) to get the file path, and then [`CopyFile()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363851.aspx) to copy the file to the same directory with a different file name.

By using [`GetLastError()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360.aspx), I am getting an error code:

> 0x2 - The system cannot find the file specified.

But when I used `MessageBox()` to see the file names, it showed the correct file names.

In addition to this, I have also tried to [`StrTrim()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773454.aspx) the file name, but still it did not work.

I am using Borland C++Builder 6.0.

---

**CODE**

```
OPENFILENAME ofn;
char szFile[260];
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));
ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner =  Form1->Handle;
ofn.lpstrFile = szFile;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = '\0';
ofn.nMaxFile = sizeof(szFile);
ofn.lpstrFilter = "All\0*.*\0Text\0*.txt\0";
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = 0;
GetOpenFileName(&ofn);

LPSTR FileName;
FileName = ofn.lpstrFile;
MessageBox (Form1->Handle, FileName, "File Name", MB_OK);
MessageBox (Form1->Handle, strcat(FileName, ".newfile"), "New File Name", MB_OK);
CopyFile(FileName, strcat(FileName,".newfile"), false);
```

---

**EDITED CODE**

I have tried using two variables, but it is still not working. Can anyone suggest a correction?

```
LPSTR FileName;
LPSTR NewFileName;
FileName = ofn.lpstrFile;
NewFileName = FileName;
strcat(NewFileName, ".newfile");
MessageBox (Form1->Handle, FileName, "File Name", MB_OK);
MessageBox (Form1->Handle, NewFileName, "New File Name", MB_OK);
CopyFile(FileName, NewFileName, false);
```

---

**WORKING CODE**

The below code works, but I had to add a Text Box / Edit Control. Is there way to do it without adding any extra control?

```
LPSTR FileName;
AnsiString NewFileName;
FileName = ofn.lpstrFile;
Edit1->Text = FileName;
NewFileName = Edit1->Text + ".bak";
MessageBox (Form1->Handle, FileName, "File Name", MB_OK);
MessageBox (Form1->Handle, NewFileName.c_str(), "New File Name", MB_OK);
```

Comment: of course not working because you change *FileName* by *strcat*. you try copy (without *MessageBox*) *FileName.newfile* to *FileName.newfile* - you need use 2 separate buffers for existinf and new file name

Comment: The first parameter is the name of an existing file and the second one is the name of the new file.

Comment: if you still not understand what you doing - can not help ). the first and second parameter in your code is the **same** - *FileName.newfile* or *FileName.newfile.newfile*

Comment: Okay, I got it.

Comment: Use the debugger. Don't be helpless.

Comment: `NewFileName = FileName` - are you understand what you doing ? you need not  two variables but 2 separate buffers for existinf and new file name .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a single buffer for both arguments of `CopyFile()`, and you are appending the new extension to that buffer, so of course `CopyFile()` is not going to find the file to copy.

You need to use two separate buffers for the two arguments of `CopyFile()`, eg:

```
TCHAR szSrcFile[MAX_PATH];
TCHAR szDstFile[MAX_PATH+12];

OPENFILENAME ofn;
ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn)); ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
ofn.hwndOwner = Form1->Handle;
ofn.lpstrFile = szSrcFile;
ofn.lpstrFile[0] = TEXT('\0');
ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;
ofn.lpstrFilter = TEXT("All\0*.*\0Text\0*.txt\0");
ofn.nFilterIndex = 1;
ofn.lpstrFileTitle = NULL;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle = 0;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir = NULL;
ofn.Flags = OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST | OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST;

if (GetOpenFileName(&ofn))
{    
    lstrcpy(szDstFile, szSrcFile);
    lstrcat(szDstFile, TEXT(".newfile"));
    MessageBox(Form1->Handle, szSrcFile, TEXT("File Name"), MB_OK);    
    MessageBox(Form1->Handle, szDstFile, TEXT("New File Name"), MB_OK);
    CopyFile(szSrcFile, szDstFile, FALSE);
 }
```

That being said, since you are using Borland's VCL framework, you should use the `TOpenDialog` component instead of `GetOpenFileName()` directly, and then you can use `String` variables for easy concatenation:

```
// these properties can also be set at design-time instead...
OpenDialog1->Filter = "All|*.*|Text|*.txt";
OpenDialog1->FilterIndex = 1;
OpenDialog1->Options = TOpenOptions() << ofPathMustExist << ofFileMustExist;

if (OpenDialog1->Execute())
{
    String SrcFile = OpenDialog1->FileName;
    String DstFile = SrcFile + ".newfile";
    CopyFileA(SrcFile.c_str(), DstFile.c_str(), FALSE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked with one correction: ofn.lpstrFile = szFile; ==> ofn.lpstrFile = szSrcFile;

Comment: @SoftwareBuilder fixed